# Play Audio file on Raspberry Pi 3B+ in Python 3 IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, pyglet, pyaudio

Installed pyglet, pygame and other libraries to run the audio file recorded using the **pyAudio** code. No error occurs and the code runs successfully but no sound is heard in the output speaker/headsets/earphones.
The audio output jack is working otherwise but **doesn't play audio** when we run any audio file through **python shell module** coding.
What can be the issue?

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys

CHUNK = 1024

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
print("Plays a wave file.\n\nUsage: %s test2.wav" % sys.argv[0])
sys.exit(-1)

wf = wave.open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
            channels=wf.getnchannels(),
            rate=wf.getframerate(),
            output=True)

data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

while data != '':
stream.write(data)
data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

Comment: Could you share the code you're using to attempt this?

Comment: Yes, Sure, I've updated my question with code. Please check now.

Comment: I might be completely mental when I say this, but does your OS compile pyaudio (Portaudio) with PulseAudio support? I'm guessing you're using pulseaudio and not Alsa alone?

Comment: No, I have used output audio jack. I didn't understand what you are asking :/ .

Comment: I just want to hear my recorded audio file through raspberry pi using any code.